# Basic PHP $_REQUEST

Tags: php, datepicker

I'm fairly new with PHP, which the following question will prove:

I have three basic `isset()` they are:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['countries'])) {
    echo "yes";
} 
else echo "no";

if  (isset($_REQUEST["depateDate"])) {
    echo "yes";
}
else echo "no";

if (isset($_REQUEST['arrivalDate'])) {
    echo "yes";
}
else echo "no";
```

This is the HTML from the form:

```
<form action="conversionOutputNew.php" method="GET">
    Depart Date:
    <input type="text" id="depateDate" name="depateDate" />

    Arrival Date:
    <input type="text" id="arrivalDate" name="arrivalDate" />

    <select multiple="multiple" name="countries[]" style="height:180px;">
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
</form>
```

What's happening is the chosen countries are being verified with the isset(), but the two dates are not. The only thing I can think of that might have an effect on the dates are that I have jQuery UI's `datepicker()` associated with it, but removing that still did not help.

I appreciate your help and input.

Comment: You're missing a `</select>`.

Comment: You're also missing a `submit`-Button

Comment: you can start by echoing the data for depateDate and arrivalDate before proceeding with your if statements to check if they have any value in them. also post would be a better choice than get, well that's my own preference anyway.

Comment: If you are new to php you may not to know that `$_REQUEST` contains content of `$_GET`, `$_POST` AND `$_COOKIE`. So if you are using just this form change `$_REQUEST` TO `$_POST`. This is not an answer on your question but this what you need to know if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible something is causing a blank value (perhaps a whitespace) to get POSTed. Since they are text fields, try doing this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['departDate']) && !empty($_REQUEST['departDate'])) {
```

Comment: A whitespace in `$_REQUEST['departDate']` would still not be "empty". But: An input field with no text (not even a whitespace) is still POSTed, thus your solution seems correct to me.

Comment: I'm still not 100% on how this was fixed, but it's working now. Thank you for your quick responses...Reading back on xbonez's response I noticed I misspelt departDate...(not sure if that was what it was since it was incorrect on both the form and form processor). thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will test for a non-empty input and validate as well:

```
// use a suitable format date for preg_match()
if ($arrivalDate = trim($_REQUEST['arrivalDate']) && preg_match('/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/', $arrivalDate)) 
    echo "My arrival date is $arrivalDate";
else
    echo "No valid input";
```

Comment: While this'd be ok for dates, if you're dealing with fields that allow spaces and/or zeroes as inputs, `empty()` will turn around and bite you in the rump.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that upon submitting the form, the dates are set (so, the isset returns TRUE), but they are empty. So, you can check for emptyness (with empty($variable) php function), to start with.

Nevertheless, I think that some more specific rules have to be set instead of relying only on isset. Especially for dates, you can check for a specific format with a regular expression (e.g. with preg_match and a regular expression like /^\d{4}-d{2}-\d{2}$/ (to match YYYY-mm-dd, the aforementioned regex can be further improved, but it is just an example).